# Folder Redirection in sbs 2008

Tags: windows-sbs-2008, folder-redirection

i have set folder redirection in the sbs console but it only allows me to this for desktop, documents and start menu but not application data. how do i get it to redirect the application data folder aswell? i no it may have somthing to do with group policies?

All my users are using windows xp the server is windows sbs 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the "Small Business Server Folder Redirection Policy" GPO to configure additional redirected folders.